# $\sigma$-algebra = complement of $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

$F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$. $F^c = \{ A : A^c \in F \}$.

How can I show that $F^c = F$?

$F$ can be a set of sets so I don't believe De Morgan's law is applicable. Therefore I would have to show that for every element in $F$ is also in $F^c$ but I'm not sure how to get it started.

Comment: Since $A\in \mathcal F^c\iff A\in \mathcal F$, the claim is rather straightforward...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that every $\sigma$-algebra is closed under taking complements. In other words, for every $A \in F$, we know that $A^c \in F$. By your definition of $F^c$, this tells us that $A \in F^c$.

This shows that us that $F \subset F^c$: can you prove the other direction?

Comment: Would proving the other direction look like:

Define event $B \in F \cap F^c$, therefore $B \in F$ and $B \in F^c$. 
If  $B \in F$, then  $B^c \in F$.

Comment: Not quite - we need to show that $F^c \subset F$. So take some $B \in F^c$, and show that it must belong to $F$. If $B \in F^c$, then $B^c \in F$, by our definition of $F^c$. Using the properties of a $\sigma$-algebra, what does that tell you about $B$?

Comment: Let $B \in F^c$ then by the definition of $F^c$ outlined above, $B^c \in F$. Because $F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, that would mean $B \in F$ also. From there, we can say $F^c \subset F$

Comment: That's right, and this completes the proof.